# Destruindo Sessão e objetos de sessão no JSF

Tags: java, jsf, session

Estou usando `session.invalidate();` para invalidar a sessão, mas quando acesso o manger do Tomcat ele me mostra que a sessão ainda existe.

O seguinte código me mostra que mesmo após usar o método invalidate() consigo exibir uma informação de um objeto que esta em sessão. Esse objeto não deveria ter sido excluído?

```
@ManagedProperty("#{usuarioController}")
private UsuarioController usuarioController;

@RequestMapping("antigo")
public String antigo(HttpSession session) {

    HttpSession s = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove("usuarioController");
    s.invalidate();

    if (usuarioController.getUsuarioLogado() == null) {
        System.out.println("OBJETO LIMPO");
    } else {
        System.out.println("OBJETO CONTINUA: " + usuarioController.getUsuarioLogado().getNome());
    }

    HttpSession s1 = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    if (s1 == null) {

        System.out.println("Sessão invalida");
    } else {

        System.out.println("Sessão valida");
    }

    if (usuarioController.getUsuarioLogado() == null) {
        System.out.println("OBJETO LIMPO");
    } else {
        System.out.println("OBJETO CONTINUA: " + usuarioController.getUsuarioLogado().getNome());
    }

    return "login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é necessário você recuperar a sessão, remover o *controller session scoped* e depois invalidar a sessão manualmente, tendo que trabalhar com coisas específicas da Servlet API. Você pode usar [ExternalContext#invalidateSession()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#invalidateSession--) diretamente, algo assim:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
```

A documentação dele é clara:

> Invalidates this session then unbinds any objects bound to it.

Ou seja, ele vai remover os objetos de sessão também :)

> O seguinte código me mostra que mesmo após usar o método `invalidate()` consigo exibir uma informação de um objeto que esta em sessão. Esse objeto não deveria ter sido excluído?

Na *response* atual você ainda conseguirá ter a informações da sessão, a requisição precisa ser concluída, mas não nas próximas requisições, por isto de ainda entrar no seu `else` e exibir **Sessão valida** na requisição atual.

Talvez seja interessante você fazer um *redirect* logo após invalidar a sessão, ajuda a evitar problemas na sua aplicação.